# Can a website read the contents of my Bookmarks folder?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, privacy

I was having a brief discussion with a friend about always clearing browser history on exit (or using incognito mode).  He didn't do it because he wanted the "smart fill" to occur whenever he typed in the web address of a previously visited site in order to save time.  I said my way around this was to put any regularly visited website in my bookmarks because the browser checked there whenever I started entering a web address, providing me with the same "smart fill" function.

My question is, can a website view the contents of my bookmarks folder, negating part of the reason for using incognito mode or clearing history on exit?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, **can a website** view the contents of my bookmarks folder, negating part of the reason for using incognito mode or clearing history on exit?

No.